# EC2 web application folder structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web application which is currently working fine on my local machine and I am now trying to get it to work on EC2.

I transferred the index.php file into the folder /var/www and I am able to access it by visiting my elastic IP (for example, `http://123.45.678.910/` ).

The trouble is that I also added the folder named restAPI into the folder /var/www which in turn has several files. When I try to access restAPI/index.php by going to the URL - `http://123.45.678.910/var/www/restAPI/index.php`, it gives me a **404 error**.

Comment: What the document root configured with your web server?

Comment: I don't know. How do I check/change it ?

Comment: That depends on what web server you are using. There is a configuration file(s) stored in /etc/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. The *file system path*
2. The *URL path*

If you're running an **Amazon Linux** image, your web content should be deployed inside `/var/www/html` -- as is the case with just about every reasonable Linux installation.

If your index page is stored at `/var/www/html/index.php`, then your URL will be `http://123.45.678.910/index.php`.

If you're trying to access `http://123.45.678.910/var/www/restAPI/index.php`, it means that you uploaded your file to `/var/www/html/var/www/restAPI/index.php`.

Make sense?